# Ask about how to insert data into many tables (with relationship) and avoid duplicate data error

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Currently I'm developing an application to import data from XML to MySQL using Spring Batch ( https://github.com/samuelwilsone/filmdata ).

This is the first time I'm working with Spring Batch so would you please guide me how to resolve some problems below:

**I have 5 tables (actors, directors, films, film_actors, film_directors). Each director can have more than 1 film, so I want to implement the program that will insert new director into "directors" table and get the id use to insert into "film_directors" table. If director has already existed, the program will get the id and insert into "film_directors" table. Actor is similar.**

Example:

With 2 files (AVATAR.xml, TITANIC.xml), I want to insert into database like this:

```
--- Table "films":
AVATAR, AVATAR 2009, 7.9
TITANIC, TITANIC 1997, 7.7

--- Table "director":
1, James Cameron

--- Table "film_directors":
AVATAR, 1
TITANIC, 1
```

**When we run the program in the second time, it will get the error because the duplicate data (data already existed in database). How can we avoid this?**

I'm very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why error, if all datas exeist in database, just skip all rows is ok, import success

Comment: Yes, I understand, I'm trying to skip this. But for the first issue, how can I insert to "director" table first and get id to insert in "films" and "film_directors"? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In reading phase you have to build a object model representing '`Director` + `Films`' (I think you can get this for free with SB XML ItemReader).

Checking for data duplication can be done in processing phase (as @zg_spring wrote).

During writing phase do `director` insert and use its new generated id for associated `films` (and `film_director` of course); this operation should be done manually using a custom `ItemWriter` or a service component embedded into an `ItemWriter` (net is full of examples)

Comment: Dear Luca Basso Ricci, thank you for your guidance. Sorry for trouble but would you please give me some examples? Or if can, could you please help me change in my source code ( https://github.com/samuelwilsone/filmdata ). Many thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have few spare time. Basically you need to read 'FileDetail\FilmInformation' tag from XML files; you have to enrich `Film` class with that new informations. Once you have all info do your works should do pretty easy